# Determining the Reynolds number from 3D velocity data

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

I have some 3D velocity data $\{v_x,v_y,v_z\}$ recorded over time at a very high frequency in an environment with anisotropic turbulence. I know that for a single (i.e. 1D) variable, we may use the autocorrelation to determine the Reynolds number as follows:

> Let $u=u(t) - U$ where $U$ is the mean velocity. We calculate $\rho(\tau) = R_{uu}(\tau)/\overline{u^2}$ where $R_{uu}(\tau) = \overline{u(t)u(t+\tau)}$. We can then determine the length scale using
>
> $L_u = U \int_0^{\tau_0} \rho(\tau)d\tau$ where $\rho(\tau_0) = 0$
>
> The Reynolds number is then given by $\mathrm{Re} = \frac{L_u \sqrt{\overline{u^2}}}{\nu}$
>
> I believe [this](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1938.0013) is the source for this approach.

This approach is designed for *isotropic* turbulence, but I am dealing with anisotropic turbulence so that I can't assign the same Reynolds number to each of the measurement axes. I need some way to aggregate the velocities to some kind of 3D Reynolds number. Up until now I have simply defined a "1D" scalar value

$$v = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$$

And applied the above approach to this quantity. However, this does not seem logical since for example $(v_x,v_y,v_z)(t) =(1,0,0)$ and $(v_x,v_y,v_z)(t+1) =(0,0,1)$ would result in $v(t)=v(t+1)$ so that there is no turbulence, while such an abrupt flow would in fact be very turbulent.

Does anyone know better methods for doing this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: But why do you need it? Since it's anisotropic one number would not be enough. Anisotropic invariants come to mind for classification.

Comment: @Bernhard ah I see. I am trying to relate some other measured quantity to how turbulent the flow is, which I would like to represent in óne scalar value. I have a large mean flow in one direction, but different flucutations along each x,y,z direction.

Comment: Why is the bulk velocity of your flow not sufficient then, for defining the Reynolds number? Any choice you make is going to be rather arbitrary, so I would always pick a simple one that makes most sense. I.e, calculate $Re$ based on the equations in the quote in your question, and then pick the largest one based on $u$, $v$ and $w$ (or do a root sum of the squares)